# How to split an entity in Entity Framework and reduce size using link tables?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

Imagine you have a simple class

```
public class Orders
{
    public int OrderId
    { 
        get; 
        set;
    }
    public string Note 
    {
        get; 
        set;
    }
}
```

Now imagine that note is a field where the representative copy pasted canned responses, or enters their own, so after a good while you have hundreds of thousands, of a highly repetitive data.
While the rep can enter his own values, most of the data 80% is just repeated.

So we want to move the strings to a separate table, and only save on the DB the distinct versions, and then link those distinct versions to the order.
Once the data is entered there is no editing, so no changes will happen on the  note data.

We want to approach this by using another two table,s one that holds the distinct, and one that has the links. But we are struggling into how configuring EF into using the distinct logic.

Now at first glance we think EF cant do this out of the box. So where can we modify and plug in something to save the note?

Comment: I guess the obvious question before attempting this is... Has there been a measurable performance improvement in the database for this approach?  It seems like adding complexity like this should be based on a known, predicted improvement.  Repeated data isn't *necessarily* a bad thing.

Comment: Our current tables, has 6,8 millions rows, taking over 20 GB of space. Before it used to be around 120 GB, but we switch the field to a gzip compression and that saved us 3/4 of space, so from 120, we saved 100 GB. It impacts the indexes since they are also huge. We are scheduled to grow 1 million rows a month. It will become unsustainalbe  in the middle to long term.

Answer (score 0):

This is almost certainly something that your database should handle. The only exception I could see is if you have a fixed number of strings `Note` could be (i.e. an `enum`).

If you use SQL Server it already does this for you. [The SQL Server Page Compression docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/cc280464.aspx) seem to indicate that if you turn on Page Compression for a table it will do exactly what you're trying to do.

Comment: We are using SQL azure, im not sure if it supports compression.

Comment: They claim they support it in some regions, see: https://feedback.azure.com/forums/217321-sql-database/suggestions/403510-allow-data-compression-to-improve-size-performanc